# Does storm hit under dark swarm?

Tags: starcraft

I just wonder what effects does a storm from Templar has under a spell cast by a dark swarm cast by defiler. Does it deal any damage at all? is the damage reduced.

I wanted to test it myself but its hard to control 2 races at once with both of the abilities researched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All special abilities (like Psionic Storm) hit under the cloud, as well as ranged splash damage (such as indirect siege tank fire) and of course melee attackers.

Blizzard's [Starcraft Compendium](http://classic.battle.net/scc/zerg/zvt.shtml) is a great resource for questions like these.

Comment: hah even after you gave me the website i cant find the information there.